# Blank page and memory size exhausted

Tags: php, symfony-3.4

I've been working for hours on this issue and I'm about to get mad ! I develop a Symfony 3 application for more than a year, without any big problem. I was implementing some DoctrineEventListeners to my User Entity, everything was fine. But I now have an Error 500 for each page I want to access to (even the ones where there is NO call to these EventListeners). And my php log says this :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/symfonyjf/var/cache/dev/ContainerXu4ttxs/getDoctrine_Orm_DefaultEntityManagerService.php on line 41
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/symfonyjf/vendor/symfony/debug/Exception/OutOfMemoryException.php on line 1
```

I reversed all my last changes, so there is no "new" EventListener in my project. But still, the project still shows a blank page.

Do you have any clue to help me ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: How about you increase PHP's allowed memory usage to something above 128MB... Unless you're on a no-budget free hosting or something 128MB is pretty low if you're running a decent sized application. Not saying you should assign 64GB but [up it to 256MB for example](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) to see if the problem goes away. If it does, find out what caused the problem and try to get it back to where you were.

Comment: In cases of slowness, or memory exhaustion, the obvious thing to do is to check where the time, or memory, is going. So you store the running time and memory usage at significant points in your code, and you check them. However, running out of memory is usually caused by an infinite loop in the code.

Comment: I increased the allowed memory usage, without any change.

Comment: I finally checked service by service and I found the one that was causing what I guess was an infinite loop. Thanks everybody !

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to clear your cache so you are sure that you are running the correct version of code. Secondly I suggest to use the Symfony Stopwatch Component in order to monitor the memory usage of different code blocks in your project in order to understand where you have the largest memory consumption. Finally, if you can (i.e. you are not using a shared hosting environment) increase PHP allowed memory in your php.ini file.

Comment: Well, the problem happens even when I want to clear the cache. Somehow I don't understand how it is possible, since it happens even when I call my homepage, to which I didn't make any change !

Comment: You can clear your cache just by deleting the var/cache/* directories.

Comment: I finally checked service by service and I found the one that was causing what I guess was an infinite loop. Thanks everybody !

Answer (score 0):

I finally checked service by service and I found the one that was causing what I guess was an infinite loop. It was an Injection of EntityManager inside a service triggered by a Doctrine EventListener, which is (I guess) not allowed.
Thanks everybody !